# How to write below Polynomial function to lambda or List Comphrention version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to create polynomial features of X and I can't build logic to make the below function in list comprehension or using Lambda.
X is an array with a shape of `(118,2)`  118 rows and 2 columns.

This function creates polynomial features of X, for instance, `X1, X2, X1**2, X2**2, X1*X2`.

```
def mapFeature(x1,x2,degree):
    """
    take in numpy array of x1 and x2, return all polynomial terms up to the given degree
    """
    out = np.ones(len(x1)).reshape(len(x1),1)
    for i in range(1,degree+1):
        for j in range(i+1):
            terms= (x1**(i-j) * x2**j).reshape(len(x1),1)
            out= np.hstack((out,terms))
    return out

X = np.random.randn(118,2)

X = mapFeature(X[:,0], X[:,1],6)
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. What is X? You're trying to extract terms from an already fitted function stored as X, or fit a certain order polynomial to data X? How is X ordered? What do you want out?

Comment: you can take a random array of shape (118,2) X  = np.random,.randn(118,2)

Comment: I guess it's very clear all this Function is doing creating polynomial features of X, for instance, X1,X2, X1**2 X2**2 ,X1*X2

Comment: So is this correct? Say I pass two polynomials of degree m and n, and a degree d, and then the function returns the coefficients of all the possible degrees upon multiplication of polynomial 1 and 2?

Comment: Exactly m are training example n are features and d is degree

Comment: What's wrong with `A = [x1, x2, x1**2, x2**2, x1*x2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's construct a simpler example:

```
In [60]: x, y = np.arange(1,4), np.arange(2,5)                                                         
In [61]: mapFeature(x, y,3)                                                                            
Out[61]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  4.,  1.,  2.,  4.,  8.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  9.,  8., 12., 18., 27.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  4.,  9., 12., 16., 27., 36., 48., 64.]])
```

This part of your code looks like its iterating over a couple of ranges and constructing a values that's a mix of powers of the 2 input arrays:

```
for i in range(1,degree+1):
    for j in range(i+1):
        terms= (x1**(i-j) * x2**j)
```

Here's a simpler example of doing this with broadcasted array powers:

```
In [62]: x[:,None]**np.arange(4,0,-1) * y[:,None]**np.arange(0,4)                                      
Out[62]: 
array([[  1,   2,   4,   8],
       [ 16,  24,  36,  54],
       [ 81, 108, 144, 192]])
```

Obviously I don't have the right `aranges`, but hopefully you have a clearer idea of how you want to arrange the powers.  I don't have time to decode your `i,j` iterations now.